# php + jquery event on starting page loading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web

Is it possible to get event on starting page loading, when DOM structure isnt complete?

For example:

```
<?php

for ($i =0 ; $i<10000; $i++)
{
    for($e=0;$e<1000;$e++) {
        $f = 5 * 4 & 9;
    }
}

echo "done";

?>
```

I have this php code, loading page in this case takes ~5 sec, and i want to event on start page loading and on the end of loading.

Event when site is ready i can get with

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    });
```

but on starting loading?
 Can someone help with it?

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: ok, so i want to do page loader (spinner) on php site, because execute php code take several seconds, so i want to get event before starting php code to run spinner and event when page will be loaded to end stop spinner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write inline javascript at the start of your page, and before these PHP codes. The browser will execute inline JS as it reads it.

edited to add:

However, that won't work in your example, because in your example, it's not the page load that takes the time, it's the server-side page generation.

You'd have to use php's flush() to flush the output buffer and push the javascript to the browser before actually doing the work.

Comment: i found solution with your tip (flush() ) function. thanks!